# My close window button is acting weird

Tags: gtk3

I'm a beginner on GNU/LINUX environments.
I have "riced" my desktop environment a bit by following a tuto on youtube.
I installed among other things a GTK theme.
My problem is that since a few days, the window close button behaves strangely.
Here are two images to explain:
[gnome-terminal instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRAD0.png)
The first one shows the gnome-terminal application. The buttons on the top right are correctly displayed.
[another application instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeb8e.png)
On the other hand, on the second picture, the close button is displayed incorrectly. This happens for example on applications such as vscode or GIMP, to name a few.

I would like to know if anyone has had this kind of graphic problem and if so, if you know how to solve it.

I think this problem is related to GTK, but i'm not really sure. If it's not the case, i apologize.

Sincerely,

MrFLish

Comment: The problem is not related to GTK, but to the theme you use. The best course of action probably is to file an issue with the developer of the theme.

Comment: Oh I see
Okay, I'll ask the developer about it

Thanks